# What happens when I jiggle my staff?

Tags: kingdom-of-loathing

I've just got my first staff, and a new button has appeared in the combat UI, allowing me to jiggle it. If I were to do so, what would happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you jiggle your [Cheffstaff](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Rodoric,_the_Staffcrafter) in combat, it will deal a predetermined amount of damage to your enemy.

Some staves will have additional effects, such as [reducing monster levels](http://kol.coldfront.net/thekolwiki/index.php/Staff_of_the_Walk-In_Freezer), etc.